how can i do a Line Chart with drag gesture in kotlin jetpack compose?
I have a kotlin file to display a composable chart(using YCharts library) but im stuck trying to do a drag gesture. I already tryied to do a Modfier.draggable() and nothing happens.
follow the code below :
enum class ChartPeriod(
    val data: PriceData,

    @StringRes
    val title: Int,
) {
    Y1(data = PriceData.Y1, R.string.y1),
    Y5(data = PriceData.Y5, R.string.y5),
    Y10(data = PriceData.Y10, R.string.y10),
    Y25(data = PriceData.Y25, R.string.y25)
}

private val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM, yyyy")

@Composable
fun CustomChart(
    period: ChartPeriod,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    var selectedPeriod by remember { mutableStateOf(value = period) }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        val dataPoints = createChartDataPoints(selectedPeriod)

        // Multipliers are used to adjust the content to width
        val multipliers = mapOf(
            AoroChartPeriod.Y25 to 1.04f,
            AoroChartPeriod.Y10 to 1.05f,
            AoroChartPeriod.Y5 to 1.07f,
            AoroChartPeriod.Y1 to 1.09f
        )

        // Compute the step size based on the chart width, to make the entire data fit on the screen
        val density = LocalDensity.current
        var chartWidth by remember { mutableIntStateOf(10) }
        val stepSize = with(density) {
            val width = chartWidth * multipliers[selectedPeriod]!! / dataPoints.size

            width.toDp()
        }

        val lineChartData = LineChartData(
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
            containerPaddingEnd = 0.dp,
            paddingRight = 0.dp,
            linePlotData = LinePlotData(
                lines = listOf(
                    Line(
                        dataPoints = dataPoints,
                        lineStyle = LineStyle(
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                        ),
                        intersectionPoint = IntersectionPoint(
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary
                        ),
                        SelectionHighlightPoint(
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                            style = Fill
                        ),
                        shadowUnderLine = ShadowUnderLine(
                            brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                                colors = listOf(
                                    MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                                    Color.Transparent
                                )
                            ), alpha = 0.3f
                        ),
                        selectionHighlightPopUp = SelectionHighlightPopUp(
                            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                            backgroundAlpha = 0.9f,
                            backgroundCornerRadius = CornerRadius(8.0f),
                            popUpLabel = { x, _ ->
                                dataPoints[x.toInt()].description
                            },
                            labelColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                            labelSize = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.fontSize,
                        ),

                    )
                )
            ),
            gridLines = null,
            xAxisData = AxisData.Builder()
                .axisConfig(
                    AxisConfig(
                        isAxisLineRequired = false
                    )
                )
                .axisStepSize(stepSize)
                .endPadding(0.dp)
                .startPadding(0.dp)
                .build()
        )
        LineChart(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(200.dp)
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    chartWidth = it.size.width
                },
            lineChartData = lineChartData
        )


        val periodTitles = ChartPeriod.values().map { stringResource(it.title) }
        CustomTabRow(
            modifier = Modifier
                //.height(32.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            titles = periodTitles,
            selectedTabIndex = periodTitles.indexOf(stringResource(selectedPeriod.title)),
            textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.labelSmall,
            onTabSelected = {
                selectedPeriod = ChartPeriod.values()[it]
            }
        )
    }
}

private fun createChartDataPoints(period: ChartPeriod): List<Point> {

    val points = period.data.points
    val dates = period.data.dates

    val yMin = points.min()
    val yMax = points.max()
    val yDiff = yMax - yMin

    val dataPoints = points.mapIndexed { index, y ->
        val yNorm = (y - yMin) / yDiff

        Point(
            x = index.toFloat(),
            y = yNorm,
            description = "${dateFormatter.format(dates[index])}: US$ $y"
        )
    }

    return dataPoints
}

I dont know how to implement that drag using the dataPoints and change the position of the SelectionHighlightPoint while im doing the drag gesture.
Follow the lib that im using : https://github.com/codeandtheory/YCharts
Im considering to test and change the lib if necessary
